# K8S Forbit job if another job is running

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to run 2 different jobs and create a relation between them, one of the jobs is running every 20mins and the second needs to run every 2 hours.

is it possible to stop the 20min job if the 2 hours job starts to run?

Comment: Is the 20 min Job dependant on the results of the 2 hour jobs in any way? Or is it a matter of resources?

Comment: @Blokje5 I have a job that goes to one of my databases and gets some entries from the last hour and caches them on my MongoDB. but I want my another job that every 2 hour - it will purge all the cache and gets all the leads from the last month. so no need for the 20min job anymore (if it still runs, all the chances that it will finish after a few mins)

Comment: This is something you have to solve by code. You can write a code that will check if the 2 hours job starts to run.

Comment: @mWatney right, but I'm afraid  that it will be inaccurately

Comment: You have to create a lock mechanism in your code. Kubernetes don't support job dependencies at this moment.